# Is there any way to force ipython to interpret utf-8 symbols?

Tags: string, utf-8, ipython, literals, diacritics

I'm using ipython notebook.

What I want to do is  search a literal string for any spanish accented letters (ñ,á,é,í,ó,ú,Ñ,Á,É,Í,Ó,Ú) and change them to their closest representation in the english alphabet.

I decided to write down a simple function and give it a go:

```
def remove_accent(n):
    listn = list(n)
    for i in  range(len(listn)):
        if listn[i] == 'ó':
            listn[i] =o
        return listn
```

Seemed simple right simply compare if the accented character is there and change it to its closest representation so i went ahead and tested it getting the following output:

```
in []: remove_accent('whatever !@# ó')
out[]: ['w',
        'h',
        'a',
        't',
        'e',
        'v',
        'e',
        'r',
        ' ',
        '!',
        '@',
        '#',
        ' ',
        '\xc3',
        '\xb3']
```

I've tried to change the default encoding from ASCII (I presume since i'm getting two positions for te accented character instead of one `'\xc3','\xb3'`) to UTF-8 but this didnt work. what i would like to get is:

```
in []: remove_accent('whatever !@# ó')
out[]: ['w',
        'h',
        'a',
        't',
        'e',
        'v',
        'e',
        'r',
        ' ',
        '!',
        '@',
        '#',
        ' ',
        'o']
```

PD: this wouldn't be so bad if the accented character yielded just one position instead of two I would just require to change the if condition but I haven't find a way to do that either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are getting two characters for the 'ó' character instead of one. Therefore, try to change it to unicode first so that every character has the same length as follows:

```
def remove_accent(n):
    n_unicode=unicode(n,"UTF-8")
    listn = list(n_unicode)
    for i in range(len(listn)):
        if listn[i] == u'ó':
            listn[i] = 'o'.encode('utf-8')
        else:
            listn[i]=listn[i].encode('utf-8')
    return listn
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, although now the output is a horizontal vector instead of a vertical one, not that it matter but why does this happen? it makes me curious

Comment: Above a certain length, IPython will display lists vertically instead of horizontally. It's exactly the same kind of object, only the display is changing.

Comment: yes, you're right. I had never paid attention to it

Comment: funny coincidence the string I chose happened to be in the verge of vertical and horizontal representation